# Drawing and displaying a smiley face (not showing)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a smiley face using the canvas tag and javascript.  I put the individual components of the face as their own methods (drawFace(), drawEyes(), drawSmile()).  I have these methods at the bottom of my code.  But nothing displays.  When I remove these methods and put all the code into one giant method it will display.

How do I display the face using those methods?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Site's Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="myDrawing" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #EEE">
    </canvas>
            <script>
                function drawFace() {
                    var canvas = document.getElementById("myDrawing");
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                    var x = canvas.width / 2;
                    var y = canvas.height / 2;
                    var radius = 75;
                    var startAngle = 0;
                    var endAngle = 2 * Math.PI;

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
                    ctx.fill();
                    }

                    function drawSmile(){
                    var x = canvas.width / 2;
                    var y = 160
                    var radius = 40;
                    var startAngle = 1.1 * Math.PI;
                    var endAngle = 1.9 * Math.PI;

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
                    ctx.lineWidth = 7;

                    // line color
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                    ctx.stroke();
                    }


                    function drawEyes{
                    var centerX = 40;
                    var centerY = 0;
                    var radius = 10;

                    // save state
                    ctx.save();

                    // translate context so height is 1/3'rd from top of enclosing circle
                    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 3);

                    // scale context horizontally by 50%
                    ctx.scale(.5, 1);

                    // draw circle which will be stretched into an oval
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

                    // restore to original state
                    ctx.restore();

                    // apply styling
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                    ctx.stroke();

                    //left eye
                    var centerX = -40;
                    var centerY = 0;
                    var radius = 10;

                    // save state
                    ctx.save();

                    // translate context so height is 1/3'rd from top of enclosing circle
                    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 3);

                    // scale context horizontally by 50%
                    ctx.scale(.5, 1);

                    // draw circle which will be stretched into an oval
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

                    // restore to original state
                    ctx.restore();

                    // apply styling
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                    ctx.stroke();
                    }
                    drawFace()

   function drawHappyFace(){
   drawFace();
   drawEyes();
   drawSmile();
}

drawHappyFace();

            </script>        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace javascript with below code.
[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7bGG7/)

You did not put "()" while defining drawEyes function.
You are using ctx in other functions, which you defined inside first function that should be global. May be some other variables need to be defined globally.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myDrawing");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                var x = canvas.width / 2;
                var y = canvas.height / 2;
                var radius = 75;
                var startAngle = 0;
                var endAngle = 2 * Math.PI;
 function drawFace() {


                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
                ctx.fill();
                }

                function drawSmile(){
                var x = canvas.width / 2;
                var y = 160
                var radius = 40;
                var startAngle = 1.1 * Math.PI;
                var endAngle = 1.9 * Math.PI;

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
                ctx.lineWidth = 7;

                // line color
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.stroke();
                }


                function drawEyes(){
                var centerX = 40;
                var centerY = 0;
                var radius = 10;

                // save state
                ctx.save();

                // translate context so height is 1/3'rd from top of enclosing circle
                ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 3);

                // scale context horizontally by 50%
                ctx.scale(.5, 1);

                // draw circle which will be stretched into an oval
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

                // restore to original state
                ctx.restore();

                // apply styling
                ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.stroke();

                //left eye
                var centerX = -40;
                var centerY = 0;
                var radius = 10;

                // save state
                ctx.save();

                // translate context so height is 1/3'rd from top of enclosing circle
                ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 3);

                // scale context horizontally by 50%
                ctx.scale(.5, 1);

                // draw circle which will be stretched into an oval
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

                // restore to original state
                ctx.restore();

                // apply styling
                ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.stroke();
                }
                drawFace()

   function drawHappyFace(){
   drawFace();
   drawEyes();
   drawSmile();
}

drawHappyFace();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra drawFace() function call just before the declaration of drawHappyFace function. And it doesn't have a semicolon after it, so it causes a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you are missing function argument parenthesis on your `drawEyes()` function. I noticed that you have a lot of repeated logic in that function as well.

Below, I have refactored your code to remove any magic numbers. You can now draw the face at any size and place it anywhere on the canvas.

```js
// =========================================================
// Main
// =========================================================
var canvas = document.getElementById("myDrawing");

drawHappyFace(canvas, {
    fill: '#00FF00',
    lineColor: '#6F0047'
}, true);

drawHappyFace(canvas, {
    fill: '#FFFF00',
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: canvas.height / 2,
    radius : 178
});

// =========================================================
// Functons
// =========================================================
function drawFace(canvas, opts) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.save();
    ctx.lineWidth = opts.radius * 0.075;
    ctx.strokeStyle = opts.lineColor;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(opts.x, opts.y, opts.radius, opts.startAngle, opts.endAngle);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = opts.fill;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawSmile(canvas, opts, flipSmile) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var radius = 40 * opts.radius * 0.0125;
    var x = opts.x;
    var y, startAngle, endAngle;
        
    if (flipSmile) {
        y = opts.y + opts.radius * 0.7;
        startAngle = -Math.PI * 0.85; //Math.PI * 0.1;
        endAngle = -0.5; //-Math.PI * 1.1;
    } else {
        y = opts.y + opts.radius * 0.1;
        startAngle = Math.PI * 0.1;
        endAngle = -Math.PI * 1.1;
    }

    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
    ctx.lineWidth = opts.radius * 0.1;

    ctx.strokeStyle = opts.lineColor;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawEyes(canvas, opts) {
    var xOffset = opts.radius * 0.5;
    var radius = opts.radius * 0.15;

    drawEye(canvas, opts, xOffset, 0, radius); // Left
    drawEye(canvas, opts, -xOffset, 0, radius); // Right
}

function drawEye(canvas, opts, centerX, centerY, radius) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Save state
    ctx.save();

    // Translate context so height is 1/3'rd from top of enclosing circle
    ctx.translate(opts.x, opts.y - (opts.radius / 3));

    // Scale context horizontally by 50%
    ctx.scale(0.5, 1);

    // Draw circle which will be stretched into an oval
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

    // Apply styling
    ctx.fillStyle = opts.lineColor;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = radius * 0.75;
    ctx.strokeStyle = opts.lineColor;
    ctx.stroke();
    
    // Restore to original state
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawHappyFace(canvas, opts, flipSmile) {
    opts = opts || {};
    
    var defaultRadius = 48;
    var options = {
        x: opts.x || (defaultRadius / 0.9),
        y: opts.y || (defaultRadius / 0.9),
        radius: opts.radius || defaultRadius,
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 2 * Math.PI,
        fill: opts.fill || 'yellow',
        lineColor: opts.lineColor || 'black'
    };
    
    drawFace(canvas, options);
    drawEyes(canvas, options);
    drawSmile(canvas, options, flipSmile);
}
```

```css
#myDrawing {
    border: 2px solid #6F6F6F;
    background: #DFDFDF;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myDrawing" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```